# PHP Deployer change Composer Version

Tags: php, bitbucket-pipelines, php-deployer

i use PHP Deployer with bitbucket pipelines my deployment worked fine until composer version 2.0 was released.
Now i need to downgrade composer to version 1 but i don't know how to set the version.

I know that i can set the PHP Version like this:

```
set('bin/php', 'php74 -d allow_url_fopen=On');
```

Hope someone can help me.

Thank you!

Comment: When asking a question, it's good if you include your actual problem as well (more than just "not working"). What actually happens?

Comment: Oh sorry, my pipeline actually uses composer 2 and this breaks my installation so i need to use composer 1.

Comment: That didn't clarify anything about what actually happens. Exactly what breaks and how? Do you get errors? If yes, then add them to the question. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I'm just pushing for trying to solve the issue instead of downgrading.

Comment: I have the same problem. If I call "dep deploy dev" it fails in the deploy:vendors task because the deployer loads the composer version 2.x. I checked the vendors.php recipe and there is an comment which says one can set the composer version with "composer_version", "version". So I added to my deploy.php file the line set('composer_version', '1.10.17') but it has no impact.

Comment: @KlotzGroßer Sorry i found no answer for this. I'm still searching, would be awesome if you share the answer when you found it

Answer (score 2):

Simply override the `bin/composer` definition in your `deploy.php` file (originally located here: https://github.com/deployphp/deployer/blob/6.x/recipe/common.php#L114-L125)

```php
set('bin/composer', function() {
    if (commandExist('composer')) {
        $composer = locateBinaryPath('composer');
    }

    if (empty($composer)) {
        run("cd {{release_path}} && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/download/1.10.17/composer.phar -o composer.phar");
        $composer = '{{bin/php}} {{release_path}}/composer.phar';
    }

    return $composer;
});
```

Comment: Rather than downloading the phar file for a particular tag directly, you can pass `--1` to Composer's installation script to get the latest 1.x version, in case they release a security fix or similar.